# Filter MySQL comma separated field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my table there is field called `agency_ids`. It will have comma separated string values like below. `a0001, a0002`. One or may agent ids can contain per record.

[image]

Now i need to search the table using given agency id.

Ex - if i give a1235 it should return both rows showed above. If i give a1234 it should return only row with a1234.

How can i do it ? I tried `agency_ids IN ('a1234')` and  `FIND_IN_SET` but it didn't work.

**Complete query -**

```
SELECT ov.*,c.name as company_name 
FROM (SELECT v.vacancy_id,v.company_id,v.designation,v.job_ref_number 
      FROM `t2o_vacancies` AS v  
      WHERE `opening_date` <= '2014-01-27' 
      AND `closing_date` >= '2014-01-27'
      AND posting_type= 'Agency' 
      AND agency_ids IN ('a1234') 
      ORDER BY v.opening_date DESC ) AS ov 
      LEFT JOIN t2o_companies AS c ON ov.company_id = c.id
```

Comment: can you show your tables structure ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `like`

```
and agency_ids like '%a1235%'
```

instead of using `IN`

```
AND agency_ids IN ('a1234')
```

`in` will allow you to specify multiple values, but it will not look at `a1234,a1235` as two different values.

Comment: It will fail if you have thi in the field `a123, a12` and the search is `like %a12%` it will retrieve both and just have to retrieve the `a12`

Comment: @gsalgadotoledo One way to overcome this issue is by adding a comma after string i.e. `like %a12,%` to ensure only `a12` is returned _(need to append a comma after last value in column if it is not there already)_, but I think having a nested table will be better in this case.

Comment: Yes @Bhushan I actually could solved the issue using something like this: `agency_ids LIKE 'a1235,%' OR agency_ids LIKE '%,a1235' OR LIKE  'a1235'`

Answer (score 1):

How about using LIKE operator instead of IN?

```
SELECT ov.*,c.name as company_name 
FROM (SELECT v.vacancy_id,v.company_id,v.designation,v.job_ref_number 
  FROM `t2o_vacancies` AS v  
  WHERE `opening_date` <= '2014-01-27' 
  AND `closing_date` >= '2014-01-27'
  AND posting_type= 'Agency' 
  AND agency_ids LIKE '%a1234%' 
  ORDER BY v.opening_date DESC ) AS ov 
  LEFT JOIN t2o_companies AS c ON ov.company_id = c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

you can sure use `where agency_ids like %a1235%` yet this might not be the best approach.

have you considered using relational database ?

if you can add another table to your schema you can do

```
table t2o_companies
normal structure......

table t2o_vacancies
normal structure......


table t2o_companies_t2o_vacancies
id company_id vacancie_id
```

i'm not sure whats your current schema is, yet if you gona need to fetch row using agency_id then i would have a join table rather than just saving them in 1 field with comma separation.

yet if you dont want to change schema, then just dont forget to index agency_ids for faster searching.